# How do I deploy a Go app with modules to AWS EB

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, go-modules

When I deploy the app, it runs fine on first install. But any following `eb deploy` procedures fail with an error that: `go.mod was found, but not expected`.
Is there a specific configuration I have to set for deploying with Go modules?
I switched to Dockerizing the app and deploying that way, which works fine. But it sounds a bit cumbersome to me as AWS Elastic Beanstalk provided specific Go environments.

Comment: AWS ELB is just a load balancer (it stands for Elastic Load Balancer), you can't deploy anything to it, and it doesn't provide specific environments for anything. Do you mean Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I meant Elastic Beanstalk. Been doing so much reading about it I got a bit mixed up. Edited the post

Comment: What version of Go are you running in EB?

Comment: Thats a bit unclear. AWS docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-go.html) state that version is 1.13, but the environment says GO 1. Which I can't imagine from installing a standard go environment.

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913831/1309818

Answer (score 4):

You can work with go modules.

**build.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xe

# get all of the dependencies needed
go get

# create the application binary that EB uses
go build -o bin/application application.go
```

and override GOPATH to point to $HOME which defaults to `/var/app/current` as given in the EB configuration management dashboard.

**.ebextensions/go.config**

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
        GOPATH: /home/ec2-user
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. I did my experiment with the same and it works all the time I do `eb deploy`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was finally able to fix it adding this line in my build.sh script file:

**sudo rm /var/app/current/go.***

So it is like this, in my case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Stops the process if something fails
set -xe

sudo rm /var/app/current/go.*

# get all of the dependencies needed
go get "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
go get "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
go get "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
go get "github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt"

# create the application binary that eb uses
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o bin/application -ldflags="-s -w"
```